# Python and BeautifulSoup shuffles my tags around?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

This has been puzzling me for a while now, and I can not figure out what's going on here.  This is the original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<book>
  <meta>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <creator>Another Author</creator>
    <language>en-US</language>
    ...
  </meta>
  <chapter>
    ...
  </chapter>
</book>
```

Then I read the file in:

```
with open(filename) as f :
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f);
    print(soup.root)
```

and that, oddly, dumps the following:

```
<html><body><book>
<meta/>
<title>Some Title</title>
<creator>Some Author</creator>
<language>en-US</language>
...
```

So why oh why is the `<meta>` tag in the soup empty, when it is not in the original XML file?  (I could swear that this worked just two weeks ago, and I could also swear that I've not touched the script.  I did make some slight changes to the XML file further down, but I fail to see a correlation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening a XML file in a HTML parser. BeautifulSoup tries to repair the HTML structure it expected.

Instead, use a XML parser, or use [BeautifulSoup in XML mode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id11):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
```

For this to work you *must* have [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) installed.

`lxml` is an excellent XML library in and of itself. You could also use the [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library included with Python; `lxml` is based on the same API but has more features.

Comment: Gee, now that worked!  But why did this not happen in the past?  Just dumb luck?  Now that you bring up lxml, I'm actually rewriting the scripts to use lxml and dump BeautifulSoup.  That's when I ran into the issue because I wanted to compare the outputs and make sure they are the same.

Comment: @Jens: BeautifulSoup has always tried to repair HTML as best as it can, but output may differ between versions, perhaps.

Comment: The "tries to repair" part makes sense, but what is broken with... oh, I happen to use the same name "meta", don't I?!  That's what confuses the parser and it closes the tag, moving children out.  Had I named the tag differently, this wouldn't have shown?!

Comment: Still wonder why this worked previously, and then failed just now.  But if it's working again, I'm not going to ponder :-)  Thanks Martijn!

Comment: @Jens: a meta-answer: I find that the question "why did this work before" rarely leads to a productive line of enquiry. Usually you discover (a) you can't reproduce what you did before, or (b) it didn't work before, you just didn't notice, or (c) it worked because the conditions for not working were not present in the examples you tested.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I wish it was that clear sometimes.  There is one single script which I use on one single XML file; the "repair" of the meta tag is a drastic change to the soup which manifested as a premature abort of the script which hadn't previously.  I didn't touch the script, nor the environment so b) is off the table, and c) as well because the conditions are very simplistic.  This leaves a) or a variation thereof.  The whole thing puzzled me, but since I am putting both script and XML to rest and replace it with a much more stable implementation—it doesn't actually matter :-)

Comment: @Jens: I'd say BeautifulSoup got upgraded, and / or the installing lxml caused BeautifulSoup to change behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was wondering about that, but I didn't actually update BeautifulSoup myself.  But now that you mention it, lxml does bring its own drop of the Soup with it, and that may have overwritten my installation and thus caused the regression.  That would actually make sense to me... :-)